# Insurance as kiddushin Kessef

Tags: halacha, marriage, money, contemporary-halacha, kiddushin-eirusin

According to Halacha, could insurance paid for  by a man be given to   a woman to count as a “Kiddushin Kessef”? Does it count as a value that the man owns that could legitimately be used. The reason I ask is because Insurance is of monetary value, but there is not an immediate guarantee it will be useful (and is conditional on say if you get into a car accident for car insurance, or getting sick with health insurance etc.)

What is the Halakha given on this question, sources (if they exist) appreciated please.

Comment: What does it mean to give someone an insurance plan?

Comment: I still don't get the case. Do you mean a man goes to a woman and says "I'll pay your health insurance premium next month and you thereby become my wife"?

Comment: Let's say the man owns the insurance company and gives her a policy without any changing of money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question and it doesn't appear to be resolved in the present time.

If I understand the essence of the question, this revolves around what insurance is considered to be, as actual money or something else. If it is considered to be actual money (a wife. is acquired in three ways, money, ketubah and physical relations), then the marriage is complete.

But insurance falls into a gray area which is by many considered to less than a *Prutah*, prior to its actual conversion into money. That the actual value of the insurance contract is less than a Prutah prior to its actual conversion.

There is also mention that use of such a thing disgraces the wife, but if the two are in agreement to accept it, then it would be permissible.

Two excellent articles from Yeshiva Har Etzion discussing the ins and outs of this question appear in the following links.

[Article 1](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/talmud/seder-nashim/massekhet-kiddushin/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3)

[Article 2](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/talmud/seder-nashim/massekhet-kiddushin/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%93%D7%A3-%D7%92-%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A3)

If you are interested in a deeper dive and can find it, I would recommend reading the classic halacha sefer on Insurance by Rabbi Menachem Slae called, הבטוח בהלכה. It was also published in English by the Israel Insurance Association in 1982 under the title, Insurance in the Halacha.

[image]